# Insert into if not exist in C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

I would like to insert data into my database if one value doesn't exist in my database.

I've got this code:

```
try
{
    SQLConnection.Open();

    string sql = "INSERT INTO shop (title, price, information) values (@chp1, @chp2,@chp3)";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, SQLConnection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chp1", title);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chp2", price);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chp3", information);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I try to insert in my database, if the value "title" doesn't exist in my database.

In stackoverflow I've founded this answer with `IF EXISTS`, but I don't see how to use it ...

Thanks in advance for your answer :)

Comment: What RDBMS do you use, is this SQL Server 2005 or later?

Comment: I use SQL server 2008.

Comment: Perfect - merge should work then.

Answer (score 9):

```
string sql = 
    "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM shop WHERE title = @chp1)
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO shop (title, price, information) values (@chp1, @chp2,@chp3)
    END";
```

Try the above